# adding style to bullets for word document in openxml

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

My client have a requirement to add particular style to bullet numbers and character in all levels.

Till now i tried to get `NumberingDefinitionsPart` from `MainDocumentPart` and trying to find out any style id for my paragraph.
Unfortunately i am not able to crack it this way since i am getting `NumberingDefinitionsPart` as null.

my list is

1. This
2. Is

The inner Xml looks like

```xml
<w:pPr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph" />
    <w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0" />
    <w:numId w:val="3" />
    </w:numPr><w:spacing w:before="80" w:line="220" w:lineRule="exact" />
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">     
    <w:t>This</w:t>
</w:r>
```

```xml
<w:pPr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph" />
    <w:numPr>
    <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
    <w:numId w:val="3" />
    </w:numPr>
    <w:spacing w:before="80" w:line="220" w:lineRule="exact" />
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">      
    <w:t>Is</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Is there anything i am missing in my document?

Can i archive it any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I replaced your inline code markers (`\``) with a code block. The easiest way to format a code block on SO is to paste your code, then select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button. This indents the whole block by an additional four spaces, instructing Stack Overflow to format it as code.